# Get object position relative to it's center, regardless of anchor point used

Tags: swift, position, anchorpoint

Is there a way to position an object relative to another objects center point (to be precise, centered on the object) regardless of what the parent objects anchor point is?

Consider the following scenario, where we want to position object B in the center of object A

```
let viewA = UIView( frame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 200, 400 )
viewA.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake( 0, 1 )
viewA.layer.position.x = 40
viewA.layer.position.y = 100

let viewB = UIView( frame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 80, 20 )
viewB.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake( 1, 0.5 )
// How to position viewB in the middle of viewA regardless of what viewA's reference point is?
```

In other words, I am trying to find out if anyone has an algorithm or system they use to be able to position an object relative to another objects center (in the middle of another object), regardless of what anchor point(s) either object is using at that time.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "viewA's reference point"?

Comment: By "viewA's reference point" i meant its anchor point. Edited original post for clarity